# How should I structure modules in a large python application?

Tags: python, design-patterns, backend, fastapi, api-design

I often write and participate in the development of web applications in Python together with FastAPI. I always use the same folder structure which is as follows:

[image]

I think the names are clear to know what is in each of them. But I want to focus on two folders: api and services. Within api are all the modules with the endpoints of the application (one module for each "Entity", for example in the module api/routers/users.py will be all the endpoints for the users. In these endpoints there is no complex logic , all the logic is in the "services" folder. So, in the module services/users.py there will be a whole class called User with the logic. In many cases that class is simply a CRUD that inherits from a BASE CRUD and doesn't even extend the class Or maybe add one or two more methods.
However, in some cases, the "entity" requires much more complex logic, it is appropriate to implement some design patterns, interfaces etc. When that happens I feel overwhelmed by having to put everything in the services/users.py module. (which implies a very large file). I've even seen how other developers continue to extend the User class (it's just an example, it can be anything) with a lot of methods that have nothing to do with the class, making the code too coupled and with low cohesion.
As a solution to that, I thought of creating a folder as such for each entity and not a module. Then it would be services/user and there have all the user logic distributed in more than one module if necessary.
But I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing in terms of design. Am I making things more complicated? Or is it a correct strategy?

Comment: Just a sidenote, I've often converted things like users.py into users/ and used an __init__.py script to ensure imports behave as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> overwhelmed by having to put everything in the services/users.py module.

Like methods and classes, a module should do
[one thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
and do it well.

Look at the top of the users module.
Does it have a """docstring"""?
No? Well, add one.

Now, you're about to add a method for a new service,
presumably something that is tightly bound to the User entity.
Go read the first sentence of the docstring, which explains
what the module is responsible for.
Does your new service fit within its purview?
If yes, append the implementation,
otherwise find or invent another module to place it in.

---

EDIT

> maybe I should just stop thinking that the modules should not be "considerably large". After all, there's nothing wrong with that.

Well, I don't completely agree with that, for three broad reasons.

## (1.) human cognition

If a module offers just one or two public symbols,
and then there's a ton of sibling modules with
somewhat similar functionality, that's not doing
the Gentle Reader any favors. The clutter has simply
been moved up a level, so one must search across modules
instead of within a module.

I like the example of
[collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html),
which """implements specialized container datatypes""".
Do I use each container equally often? No.
But they make sense, they cohere together, and I know where to go looking.

Humans readily keep track of seven or so items.
Double or triple that can be fine.
I *love* to make
[beautiful soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#making-the-soup),
but the object that comes back has 133 public members.
(Ok, in fairness 96, after stripping out get_text vs getText synonyms.)
I assert that, like PL/I keywords and php builtins,
some modules such as the venerable `numpy` (575)
and pandas (119) `DataFrame` (208)
offer an embarrasment of riches, too many riches,
more than I keep track of or even know to go looking for.
And that's even after `DataFrame` has admirably
gone to the trouble of hiding 139 `_private` elements.

I'm glad they offer so much, and I'm not suggesting
to re-org them at this point.
But keep in mind that you don't necessarily want
your design to end up like that, for the sake
of some newly hired engineer who has to learn
your Public API.
If you break out even one or two subcategories,
then when future maintenance engineers add
One More Feature they will be guided by your example,
and perhaps add the feature to an existing small category,
or will be emboldened to invent a new category.

## (2.) import speed

The minimum unit of granularity for accessing your library
is `import`. Even if an app-level developer
does `from numpy import NaN`, that still requires
a full parse of the numpy module, discarding all which is not NaN.
The full memory footprint of the module hangs out behind the scenes,
cached, in case other symbols might be requested.

A large module will tend to sprout a bunch of deps,
which in turn have transitive deps.
The app developer incurs the cost of all those nested `import` dependencies.

So a large module does not come "for free",
it always takes some milliseconds to import it.
At the time you find yourself adding a new dependency
which your new feature relies on, you should
ask yourself, "is a new module appropriate?",
"would some consumers only want A, without the expense of loading B?"

## (3.) compatibility

Python code is pretty portable, but sometimes the code or its deps
will insist on a version range of some library, or a certain OS,
or a recent interpreter.

Conda, poet, and pip do a pretty good job of
untangling the proverbial DLL hell, but there's no 100% guarantee.
If you *can* offer core services to some consumers of your library
with minimal deps, you should, to ease their upgrade versionitis pains.

Comment: The "docstring" tip is definitely something I should implement. But imagine I have a module called "statistics". Then I want to implement the design pattern strategy and create classes for different "algorithms" that inherit from an interface. Well, it's related to statistics, but maybe I should put it in another module to avoid making statistics.py too long. But for example in a current application in which I develop services has more than 50 modules (without implementing my idea of folders instead of modules). So I could end up with more than.... I don't know... 100 modules.

Comment: You are free to write """This module computes statistics.""" or to write """This module computes Bayesian statistics of lab equipment measurements specified to have zero-mean Gaussian noise.""" The first module might wind up being a bit bigger. The design choice is yours.

Comment: Well, maybe I should just stop thinking that the modules should not be "considerably large". After all, there's nothing wrong with that. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try some design approaches with `Django` and `django-rest-framework`.

You will divide your application into small applications. Use the router module to map URLs to specific applications. Then within each application, there will be separate `models`, `services`, `serializers`, and `views`. Additionally, scripts/controllers that are commonly used can be placed in the `src` folder.

This coding approach is very effective if you are familiar with OOP (I always recommend using OOP for large projects).

[image: django project]

Comment: It is another valid option as well! Thank you!

Comment: Agreed, I like structuring bigger FastAPI applications this way too. There are (at least) two ways to "slice" an application, by technical functionality (models, schemas, routes, etc.) and by subject area/domain (users, payments, inventory, etc. etc.). When you're actually writing the code, it's in my experience way more likely that you're working in one of these domains, so if you use the technical division, you're gonna hop between folders all the time. So to me, it makes way more sense the "Django way", to divide into folders by domain, and then have files for the technical areas.